# Ceiling(RowNumber) function and SSRS charts

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating charts for data that is very simple: Students with grades from different subjects, from 2 semesters

- Autumn semester which is '`Report 1`'
- Spring semester which is '`Report 2`'

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT txtPupilID, txtSubjectName, txtForename, txtSurname, txtGrade, intReportID 
FROM ReportDB 
WHERE (intReportID = '1') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT txtPupilID, txtSubjectName, txtForename, txtSurname, txtGrade, intReportID 
FROM ReportDB 
WHERE (intReportID = '2') 
order by txtPupilID
```

I have to create charts for each subject and print them 9 on a page. My graphs worked fine and after a long time trying many things, I finally managed to print the graphs horizontally and vertically, using the ceiling function `{=(ceiling(RowNumber(nothing)/3)}`. However, this function seems to 'break' my chart because I now have 2 graphs for each subject instead of 1 (i.e. 1 graph for Report 1 and 1 graph for Report 2).

So instead of having one chart for the subject 'English', where grades from Autumn and Spring semesters are shown next to each other, I have 2 charts for 'English', one for Autumn and the other for Spring. I have attached screen shots of the charts below:

What I had before the ceiling function:

[image: What I had before the ceiling function]

What I now have after the ceiling function:

[image: What I now have after the ceiling function]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem? Does it lie somewhere in my dataset? grouping/sorting issues?

Report screenshot:

[image: Report screenshot]

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to show a sample of your dataset and a screen shot of your report design layout. Also show your group expressions. Once people can see that info  it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Where are you using the `ceiling` expression and what issue are you trying to resolve with it?

Comment: Thank you both for your messages.

Steve-o169: I was trying to print 9 charts on a page (landscape), as I have about 18 subjects so I would end up with 2 pages per child. I used the ceiling(RowNumber) function on the row and the column grouping.

AlanSchofield: below is the dataset and the report. The Rowgrouping and the Columngrouping are both using the ceiling function. As I mentioned earlier, this enables me to achieve print out of 9 charts per page, but unfortunately it also breaks my graphs, which I don't know why.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT txtPupilID, txtSubjectName, txtForename, txtSurname, txtGrade, intReportID
FROM ReportDB
WHERE (intReportID = '1')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT txtPupilID, txtSubjectName, txtForename, txtSurname, txtGrade, intReportID
FROM ReportDB
WHERE (intReportID = '2')
order by txtPupilID

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55087084/edit) that query into your question?  Also, I'm not sure that the `ceiling` expression is necessary in column grouping.  Page breaks are ignored in column grouping anyways.